# C++ Как наиболее правильно определить класс в неймспейсе другого класса?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Требуется, чтобы классы `hero` и `SpawnEnemies` находились в пространстве имен класса Engine.

```
namespace Engine {
#include "hero.h"
class SpawnEnemies;
}

class Engine
{
...
}`
```

Как наиболее правильно, с точки зрения хорошего стиля, это сделать?

Comment: Что-то у меня ощущение, что под "пространством имен класса" у вас подразумевается что-то не то... От того, что вы назовете пространство имен именем класса, оно не становится пространством имен класса, что бы под этим не подразумевать... Для меня это - пространство имен, в котором находится класс. А для вас?

Comment: Я бы не стал добавлять инклюд внутри namespace

Comment: Стиль - это такая штука, которая может быть одновременно хорошей для одного и плохой для другого. Поэтому я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, дабы не плодить холиваров.

Comment: Я хочу, что бы два класса были определены только в пространстве имен третьего. Мой код - пример того, как я пытался найти выход из ситуации, и, соотвественно, поступил неверно. Стоит ли вобще делать так, как я хочу, т.е. определять классы в пространстве имен других, если нигде больше они не используются (по крайней мере, не должны)? Может так и не делают, и я высосал из пальца эту проблему.

Comment: Насчет инклюда - полностью согласен, мне это тоже жутко не нравится, и я уверен, что так не делают, поэтому и ищу другой выход.

Comment: Может Вам нужен просто вложенный класс, без пространств имён вовсе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению не могу сходу привести ссылок на какие-то стандарты оформления кода, но, на мой взгляд, наиболее естественно будет выглядеть такой вариант:

```
//Hero.h
namespace Engine {
class Hero{
//...
};
}

//SpawnEnemies.h
namespace Engine {
class SpawnEnemies{
//...
};
}

//Engine.h
namespace Engine {
class Engine{
//...
};
}
```

**PS:** Хотя, для того, чтобы не создавать путаницы, возможно стоить придумать для пространства имен какое-то другое имя